# Suggestions for a productive hardware setup with excellent virus protection

Tags: security, antivirus

This question is a little opinion based, but I think it can be based in fact and I would prefer answers backed up with a link to a reputable company if possible.

The problem is at my job, we have "okay" hardware for the developers, laptops running Windows XP (I know) with dual core 2.3 Ghz processor, 2GB of memory and 60 GB hard disk @7200 rpm however, the amount of virus scan and security agents and big brother software on these make them unusable when scans are running.  My company insists on running full disk virus scans every monday and "smart scans" every other day.

I appreciate the concern for viruses as much as the next guy, however it is hindering our work and we are looking for a new setup that allows the developers to work unimpeded by scans, yet provides virus protection et al that the company is looking for.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This question might be better suited for serverfault.com since it isn't programming related, but rather IT related.

Comment: I would also concur with Ben S, this question probably belongs on ServerFault instead of StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks Ben, I'll post it over there as well.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305709/slowdown-of-microsoft-visual-studio-due-to-different-virus-scanner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) Try to change the scanning frequency/schedule - the machines are presumably running on-access scanning, so don't need to be doing scheduled scans.

b) If the policy is immutable; profile the machine to see what resource is being exhausted. It's probably the disk - laptops tend to have poor disks, and both AV-scheduled-scan and development/compilation tend to stress IO. So look at putting the fastest disks in the laptops - or even SSD.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just schedule the scans for when the computers aren't in use? This would lead to a higher power consumption, but would save you the burden of suffering through the scans.

You could also change the priority of the scanning applications so that they only use up idle CPU and IO time.

Comment: WOL _Wake on LAN - could mitigate the length of time the PCs have to be left on, perhaps?

Comment: The problem is we have laptops, which we are required to take with us at the end of the day (because we have cubes).  To run the scan at night, means I have to boot up at the end of the day at home.  We've brought this up to the powers that be before, but they didn't particularly care for the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at Avast? [Avast.com](http://www.avast.com) I use the free home edition on all the computers around the house running Windows and have not noticed any slowdown and/or viruses since using it. They also have a professional/enterprise version that might work for you.

In addition, what about using Firefox with Adblock and NoScript for your web browsing?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately our Enterprise antivirus is Symantec.