# Antivirus (Symantec Endpoint) configuration for developer machine

Tags: java, performance, antivirus, symantec

What are your "Symantec Endpoint" configuration recommendations for a developer PC? We do java development with Eclipse, IntelliJ, Ant and Tomcat. With "Symantec Endpoint" the build and server startup are quite slow.

Replacing or removing Symantec is not an option. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111226/least-intrusive-antivirus-software-for-development-pc, http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000803.html and http://www.theserverside.com/news/thread.tss?thread_id=44775

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305709/slowdown-of-microsoft-visual-studio-due-to-different-virus-scanner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also exclude from scanning java.exe. Make sure you add eclipse.exe too, or make eclipse start as a java.exe process, there is info on how to do that in some question here too.

Not an antivirus thing, but I would also disable windows indexing service.

Comment: Do you have links to the questions that you reference?

Comment: I said it wrong, by def shows java.exe instead of eclipse.exe, but you get the idea

Comment: glad it did, and BTW, add javaw.exe too!

Answer (score 3):

With any on-demand anti-virus program, make sure your code tree (source and build) are excluded from on-demand scans.  I have seen this change a build from taking minutes to taking seconds.