# How to run java once on window start up?

Tags: java, jvm

Due to a suite of antivirus and security policies, a java applet I developed for my organization loads very slowly. The problem is not the cache or the applet, but rather it's JVM. When Windows first loads, if I go to command window and enter "java", it will take nearly a minute for the response (the command usage text) to come up. Subsequent commands are responded immediately.

So, one mitigation I can think of is to set all users to run java once as they login. I can either put a shortcut to Start Up folder in the start menu, or create a registry key. If I want this to be as least intrusive as possible (load it in background and in low priority), what's the best way to do this?

Comment: Another option besides adding a link to the Startup folder is to create a "Windows Task".  Tasks have the added benefits of more flexibility as to when it runs (you can choose between user logon or computer startup, for example) and assurance it can run in the background with no window.  Q: Why is the initial startup so slow???  I would encourage you to get to the root cause, rather than apply band-aids. IMHO...

Comment: Thanks for your comment and Scheduler is probably what I will end up using. The root cause is the anti-virus suite. I am pretty sure of it.

Comment: Take a look at these links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1389904/antivirus-symantec-endpoint-configuration-for-developer-machine, http://forum.processing.org/one/topic/processing-very-slow-to-load-java-issue.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you consider `Windows Task Scheduler` and task that starts on windows start-up?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the call to java to the registry, under

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376977(v=vs.85).aspx

But what about not using java?