# How to speed up Visual Studio 2008? Add more resources?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, memory, cpu, performance

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 (with the latest service pack)
I also have ReSharper 4.5 installed.
ReSharper Code analysis/ scan is turned off.
OS:  Windows 7 Enterprise Edition

It takes me a long time (2 minutes) to run the debugger, compiler, and if I save a file in my app_code folder it locks up for 2 minutes.

I have 12 Gb of ram and as you can see I have plenty more.
This screen shot was taken when VS was frozen/locked up.

Can I allocate more ram to VS? Or is there any other tweaks I can do?

[image: slow]

Comment: Have you work on the same VS project/solution on a different system before? 2min sounds oddly long.

Comment: you said Win7 Enterprise. Is this at work? Do they have some sort of on-access scanner? We have etrust by CA installed and it often destroys performance.

Comment: try VS 2010 beta 2 and you'll start appreciating VS 2008's speed right away.

Comment: Hey ssg, are you saying that vs2010 is much slower?

Answer (score 7):

Looks like either a slow hard disk or a slow network to me. Any of the relevant files stored on the network?

Comment: I found that when the solution is on a usb drive it's much slower.

Answer (score 4):

Try removing ReSharper and see what happens. 
Is there an active virusscanner? What happens when you disable it for a moment?

Oh, and can you move your classes from app_code to an external library? I am not sure, but I think a change in app_code can result into a complete recompile.

Comment: IMO - Somehow ReSharper adds significantly to VS startup time. VisualAssistX is more moderate here.

Answer (score 3):

Probably hard drive speed.  This blog post from scottgu is a little old but it is still relevant:
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/11/01/tip-trick-hard-drive-speed-and-visual-studio-performance.aspx

Answer (score 3):

This may not address everything, but memory constraint issues are pretty common with ReSharper. Yet, I am addicted to it, and the speed improvements of removing it didn't outweigh the withdrawl pain...

By default, Visual Studio will only address 2GB of memory. However, you can make it large memory aware (so it will use up to 3GB) by following these steps (from [this Steven Harman post](http://stevenharman.net/blog/archive/2008/04/29/hacking-visual-studio-to-use-more-than-2gigabytes-of-memory.aspx)):

1. Be sure to backup devenv.exe
2. Using the Visual Studio command prompt, navigate to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\
3. execute the following command: `editbin /LARGEADDRESSAWARE devenv.exe`

Also, [see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8440/visual-studio-optimizations), which has some other great tips for overall Visual Studio performance. Every little bit helps.

Try that, and get yourself a faster (10,000 RPM) hard drive. Plenty of posts ([here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8440/visual-studio-optimizations), on [Coding Horror](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000800.html), and [elsewhere](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/11/01/tip-trick-hard-drive-speed-and-visual-studio-performance.aspx)) attest to the performance gains of moving from a standard 5,400 RPM to a faster model.

Comment: Also note that you might need to set the environment variables via vcvars32.bat else editbin might complain that mspdb80.dll does not exist.

Comment: Hello,
I got an error when trying this. Note the 1st time I executed it I have VS 2008 open. Then I closed it, and tried again. Same error.
http://img515.yfrog.com/img515/3962/devenverror.gif

Comment: if `EditBin` path is not set - use: `Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE>..\..\VC\Bin\X\EditBin /LARGEADDRESSAWARE DevEnv.exe` where **X** = `.` | `AMD64` | `x86_AMD64` -- test by running `EditBin` first.

Answer (score 0):

Try running [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) and use Tools/Process Activity Summary to show if any of the processes on your system are causing a large amount of file accesses, registry accesses or network activity.  If you filter the log for the name of the file you're trying to save to then it may also show some API errors or permissions problems that are causing the slowdown.

Answer (score 0):

A faster hard drive maybe your solution. Jeff Atwood has a [blog entry](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000800.html) about using a 10,000 rpm hard drive in a computer.

[Another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305709/slowdown-of-microsoft-visual-studio-due-to-different-virus-scanner)  here on Stackoverflow talks about Visual Studio slow downs due to virus scanners running.

I myself have run into large solutions taking a long time, CodeRush Express causing thing to run slow, background processes running that cause slow downs.

Good luck in your hunt. It would be interesting to know what you find.

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure that you're using the latest version of [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/download/index.html) (4.5.2)? There were a fwe good performance gains made in the last update. Myself, I've got a 28-project web solution with 1,400 source files, a 5400 RPM drive (yeah, I know), and my startup time for debugging the project is less that 30 seconds.