# Visual Studio 2019 - Builds are taking much longer that they should

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I was moving along nicely up until a couple of weeks ago when all of a sudden the build on my web project - I have three - takes up to 5 minutes to build.

The other two projects take next to no time to build.

I Changed the build setting to "Detailed" and I've found that its hanging on the following:

```
Using shared compilation with compiler from directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn
```

I have done nothing to create this and wonder if there has been an update that now requires Roslyn... and I am not sure what Roslyn is.

I did find [THIS](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/553673/compile-roslyn-problem-with-newest-vs-2019-v-1603.html) but I am at the most up to date preview version at the moment...

Does anybody know this or has gotten this and if so were they able to fix it..

**UPDATE**

I know this is NOT what people want to hear about this.  I was using Visual Studio 19 16.4.0.  Tonight I upgraded to 16.4.1 and did a build.. spot on. It built exactly as it should have with no 5 minute delays. So I am chalking this down to a dud build on behalf of MS and VS.. I suppose it happens..

Comment: have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12095718/visual-studio-build-very-slow There is an answer that was upvoted 90 times, so it might work even if the studio is way too old.

Answer (score 2):

According to your issue, the issue could be more related to some changes to VS environment, interference of some extensions or OS.

You can try my steps to troubleshoot your issue.

1. delete all files from path C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp and also delete all files in this folder(open Run and type the command prefetch)
2. then open VS and select Tools-->Import and Export Settings-->Reset all settings to reset all settings
3. close VS and then start VS with [devenv /safemode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/safemode-devenv-exe?view=vs-2019) to eliminate the interference of extensions.

In addition, try to check your Operating System and if it is not the latest, please update it because there is also a case where the operating system conflicts with VS.
Hint from [here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/15662).