# Low CPU usage during C# compiling in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio

When Rebuilding a website (single project) in Visual Studio 2019, with hundreds of .cs files, Visual Studio seems to use only 5% of the available CPU.

Any ideas of what might be causing this?

Comment: The limiting factor might not be the CPU, but disk I/O.

Comment: Disk I/O is barely above 2% in the Task manager.

Comment: How long does it take to compile?

Comment: Rebuild takes around 3 minutes on a Ryzer 5600 CPU.  800 .cs files.

Comment: 800 files in a single project? Yikes. Have you considered splitting them into distinct projects? That way you don't need to recompile them all every time you make a change.

Comment: It is a website, mostly codebehind .cs files, so rebuilds are not common.

Nevertheless it is still annoying when it happens and I find it the low CPU load curious.

Comment: AFAIK Visual Studio will only use multiple CPUs/cores/threads for multiple projects. Building a single project cannot be parallelized by VS. But be aware that projects can only be built in parallel if they don't depend on each other.

Comment: [/MP (Build with Multiple Processes)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/mp-build-with-multiple-processes)

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12095718/visual-studio-build-very-slow) can help you?